# Regular Expression for a fixed text followed by a date

Tags: regex, soapui, ready-api

I need to write a regular expression to check the text Price:12-Jun-2017 where date can change.

I am working on SOAPUI at the moment and would like to add a JSONPath RegEx Assertion for checking this text.
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: maybe add some trials you made?

Comment: This one doesnt seem to be working /^Price :$/i[0-9]{2}[-|\/]{1}[0-9]{2}[-|\/]{1}[0-9]{4}

Comment: Do you care if the date is valid? (regex can't do proper date validation)

Comment: Yes i want to check if date is valid one and in the format dd-MMM-YYYY.

Comment: Instead of regex, substring the date part and check it's validity by creating a date object

Comment: @user8137030, please check the answer and see if that is suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that `ReadyAPI` used in your case.

Select the right `JsonPath Expression` and `Regular Expression` as below value

```
Price:\\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\\d{4}
```